# syntax error on create table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When I use this code to create a table in my access db, I get an error message saying that there is a syntax error in my create sentence
What am I doing wrong.

```
Dim min_path As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
Dim min_path_trimmed As String = Replace(min_path, "file:\", "")

Dim SQL As String
Dim objCmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim Con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + min_path_trimmed + "\db.mdb")
SQL = "CREATE TABLE Names (LastName VARCHAR(30), FirstName VARCHAR (30))"
Con.Open()
objCmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Con.Close()
MsgBox("Table has been created")
```

Comment: Maybe the space between `VARCHAR` and `(30)` in the `FirstName` column?

Comment: MS Access doesn't have VarChar data type only Text data type see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Query from

```
SQL = "CREATE TABLE Names (LastName VARCHAR(30), FirstName VARCHAR (30))"
```

to

```
SQL = "CREATE TABLE Names (LastName Text(30), FirstName Text(30))"
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference at all.

Comment: Alright I thought your using ADOX, because you can't just create table using OLEDB Command see this link HOPE this help you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317867 or http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_database/microsoftaccess/article.php/c5149/Create-a-Microsoft-Access-Database-Using-ADOX-and-Visual-Basic-NET.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the way to create table in the database

```
    Dim databaseName As String = "D:\NewDB.mdb"

    Dim tableName As String = "Employee"


    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\NewDB.mdb")

    con.Open()

    Dim dbSchema As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, tableName, "TABLE"})

    con.Close()


        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [" + tableName + "] ([EmpName] TEXT(10), [EmpAddress] TEXT(10))", con)

        con.Open()

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Table Created Successfully")

        con.Close()
```

If you get any errors please feel free to post back

I will be glad to help.

Regards.